# Python Pandas .loc function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have some question. I want to change one value in a column. Is there any diff in output between this two examples?

```
wards.loc[wards['ward'] == '1', ['ward']] = '61'
```

&

```
wards.loc[wards['ward'] == '1'] = '61'
```

Thanks for replies.

Comment: You can also simply do: `wards['ward'] = wards['ward'].replace('1', '61')` This is simpler in my opinion, but they are just about the same amount of characters, and I think a direct replace would be more performant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is difference.

- The first one will select all columns of the dataframe where the criteria has matched.
- And the second one will select only the `ward` column as a dataframe where the criteria has matched.
- But if you not use `[]` then it will get a series.
- Also these are don't different if `ward` is the only column in dataframe.